# 3D Model Warps Texture (when rendered in browser)

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, gltf

Let me start with an apology: I'm very new to Blender and know very little about it.
Mainly I work as a developer and am trying to implement a 3D model in a web app for my startup. A junior designer was nice enough to make some models for us, but she is not sure why they don't render properly and lacks the time to investigate it more throughly.

**With that out of the way, let me explain the problem:**

I'm working on a fashion design editor. We have glTF models of hoodies and want to allow users to add design elements to them.

The app runs on Next.js and uses *React Three Fiber* and *drei* to render and manipulate the models.

Since the problem I've been struggling with is a bit hard to describe, I will post some images to illustrate it:

[image]

This is what it looks like before the texture is changed.
The beige square on the left is a canvas that is turned into a texture and laid over the model. It won't be visible to the end user, but is useful for development.

When I try to use text, tiny details of the texture will be applied to the model (rather than the full texture):

[image]

Instead of showing the text, the whole model takes on a weak hue of the text color (I used red to make this a bit more obvious, with black text it would be a grey hue, etc).

If I keep everything as is and just add one space of the text string, the hue becomes more pronounced:

[image]

Something very similar happens when I use images (which are applied by the same method, i.e. rendered on a canvas, turned into an image, then overlaid on the model as a texture):

[image]

#### Investigating the Problem

Since my background is technical, I started out by testing my code to make sure that the problem indeed comes from the model and not from the way it is rendered. After extensive testing, I'm rather sure that the problem does indeed stem from the model itself (rendering works as it should when I use models of random objects from Poly Haven instead of our Hoodie model).

I then turned my attention to Blender and tried a multitude of different export settings. None of them worked, which leads me to the assumption that the issue is in the materials/textures themselves.

Right now I'm on the 3rd day of familiarising myself with Blender. I'm exploring the `Shading` panel, but am not sure if this is the right place to look.

Apologies again for the vagueness of the problem and my lack of Blender skills, but if anyone has any ideas what might cause the issues I'd really appreciate your thoughts.

Thanks a lot,
Daniel

---

Edit:

Here is a screenshot from the `Shading` panel:

[image]

And another one from the `UV Editing` panel:
[image]

The UV Editing panel as a whole looks rather empty, so the suggestion that mapping is missing seems like it might be correct.

Comment: All the images you've posted have been from 3rd party software. Post some images of what it looks like in Blender, particularly the shading node setup which you can view by clicking the 'Shading' tab in the top toolbar. You'll need to click the Material icon (next to bottom on the R/H panel) to view the material properties first.  You can save images of Blender's screen from Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu.

Comment: Apart from you mentioning Blender I see absolutely nothing Blender related here... so it's hard to help you if we don't know what it is you're doing in Blender.

Comment: Hi, DTX. We have to establish whether this is solvable inside Blender. Further to @JohnEason 's comment, could you show us the [UV Map](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/uv/unwrapping/introduction.html#getting-started) of the model, if any. This texture shows every sign of being entirely interpolated from a region of the image, rather than being mapped at all.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions (and sorry for the lack of detail in the original post).

@JohnEason I have added a screenshot of the Shading panel to the original post. Also, thank you for the suggestion on the screenshot mechanism.

Comment: @RobinBetts I think you're really on to something. I have added a screenshot from the UV Editing panel and it seems like there really is not much there. All the panels on the right-hand side look mostly empty.

Comment: @DTX .... hmmmm ... what happens if you set the X and Y scales in the _Mapping_ nodes of your shader-tree to 1 ?

Comment: Thanks @RobinBetts. I see the logic and thought it would work, but after setting all of them to 1, I'm still getting the same behavior.

Comment: @DTX We may move this conversation to chat, to avoid comment-clutter. The picture showing the UV Map 'UVMap' _is_ with all faces selected? I'm assuming, for IP reasons, you can't share the .blend file.. if you could, it would be on https://blend-exchange.com/ . If you can see no UV map, you're going to have to arrange a mapping, somehow. Ideally, _before_ any deformation (by cloth simulation, or whatever)

Comment: I see nonuniform texture scaling. I have an answer for questions about glTF nonuniform texture scaling here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283597/18161